# How do I sign exes and dlls with my code signing certificate

Tags: code-signing

(I purchased a code signing cert from Thawte and have been going out of my mind with frustration at the whole process.

What I have from them are:

- .spc / .p7b file
- .pvk file

(NOTE I do not have a pfx file from them.  God knows why, but I have been fighting with their tech support for a week)

In any case I find "help" links on their site and at MS for signcode.exe which is useless for me because I can't find that exe on my machine, however I do have signtool.exe.

Unfortunately i am mystified at the command line parameters [listed on this MS help site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa387764).

Specifically, what parameters do I use and what values?  I tried what I thought was obvious but it does not work at all.

I can get the signing wizard to work, however I need this to work non-interactively in a hudson CI batch file.

It really doesn't seem like it should be this difficult, but so far it is all black magic.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you can generate your own pfx file using the pvk2pfx tool described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549703(VS.85).aspx

Something like

```
pvk2pfx -pvk cert.pvk -spc cert.spc -pfx cert.pfx -pi password
```

ought to do the trick.

Secondly, signtool is the tool you're after. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387764(VS.85).aspx

```
signtool sign /?
```

Gets you the help, but the basic command you're probably after is

```
signtool sign /f cert.pfx /p password target.exe
```

Which will sign target.exe. It gets more complex if you want to put the certificate into the certificate store on the machine (this is the CSP bit). This is really useful though for doing signing on a lot of dev machines, or on build lab machines where you want to avoid putting the certificate in source control.

Comment: Yes, signtool is the one I am trying to use but there is really no explanation of what the arguments are if I don't use a pfx file.  (It is assumed that one is familiar with all the jargon for certificates.)

Comment: The problem was I was trying to use it with spc and pvk files, not a pfx as I was unaware of the pvk to pfx utility.  Thanks!

Comment: You almost certainly want to add a timestamp using the /t http:// timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll (you can choose another server, but VeriSign is usually a good choice) option - otherwise, the signature won't be marked as valid after the certificate expires in a year or two.  The timestamp command should be part of the "basic command" because too many people seem to forget it and run into problems later on. (note the /t command has a space to prevent the "http" being removed)