# User account control message with yellow banner while running .msi Created by wix installer

Tags: c#, wix, certificate, installation

I had created .msi file to install my C# windows application , i had used wix toolset to create this .msi .
while installing this .msi file , it display user account control message with yellow banner as shown in this image [User Account Control with yellow banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJnwl.png)

it does't display the publisher name although i had wrote it inside the installer.

I want it to appear with blue banner that displays the publisher name as following image [User account control with blue banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdZeX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says that you have to **sign** your msi file using a certificate and `signtool.exe`. See:

- [this article from Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835561(v=ws.10).aspx)
- or [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090865/how-to-sign-an-msi)

Installer without signature:

[image: uac screenshot]

Installer with signature:

[image: uac screenshot]

The strange thing here is the MSI name `61913df.msi`, the filename originally is `SampleSetup1.msi`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help 2

Comment: do u have any idea if the signing thing responsible about displaying windows smart screen ??

Comment: @Laila I tried it myself with [this step-by-step instruction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows) and it worked nice. My installer got a blue uac banner. SmartScreen-filtering seems to be different, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311203/how-to-pass-the-smart-screen-on-win8-when-install-a-signed-application) for an example...

Comment: Use the `/d` option to provide a description text. In your case `SampleSetup1.msi`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz.aspx